# Trouble parsing table class with href in Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I am very new to JSOUP, have only been using it for a couple days, learning mostly from this website. Now I'm trying to get some information from the below HTML:

```
        <td class="day no-repetition">Sun</td>
        <td class="full-date" nowrap="nowrap">17/05/15</td>
        <td class="competition"><a href="/national/england/premier-league/20142015/regular-season/r25191/" title="Premier League">PRL</a></td>

          <td class="team team-a ">
              <a href="/teams/england/sunderland-association-football-club/683/" title="Sunderland">
                Sunderland
              </a>
          </td>

        <td class="score-time score">
          <a href="/matches/2015/05/16/england/premier-league/sunderland-association-football-club/leicester-city-fc/1704225/" class="result-draw">           
            0 - 0
          </a>
        </td>
          <td class="team team-b ">
            <a href="/teams/england/leicester-city-fc/682/" title="Leicester City">
              Leicester City
            </a>
          </td>
        <td class="events-button button first-occur">
        </td>

          <td class="info-button button">

              <a href="/matches/2015/05/16/england/premier-league/sunderland-association-football-club/leicester-city-fc/1704225/" title="More info">More info</a>

          </td>
```

I need to extract the Home team, score and the Away Team from the above however I am currently having issues with this. I need both the link and the text itself. Below is the code I have:

```
     try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        Element table = doc.select("table[class=matches]").first();
        Elements rows = table.select("tr");
        for (int i=0; i<rows.size(); i++){
            Element row = rows.get(i);
            Elements data = row.select("td[class=team.team-a]");

            System.out.println(data.text());

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This hasn't worked so far. I tried 'team.team-a', 'team.team.a' and all other variations of it. I managed to get the data that's in the 'competition' class, which works when I just replace ("td[class=team.team=a]") with (td[class=competition]) however this doesn't work with any of the classes that have a link.

Assistance would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just separate multiple classes with a dot:

```
td.team.team-a > a  // first team
td.team.team-b > a  // second team
td.score > a  // score
```

Comment: Seems I was missing the 'td.' in the front. Rookie error, I guess. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but the above got me the name of the team itself - how would I go about getting the link itself? The bit that's inside the <a href="">?

Comment: @Axotic, You could do something like `doc.select("td.team.team-a > a").first().attr("href")`.

Comment: @JonasCz that definitely makes life easier lol. Thank you very much!